# Find the value of $\int\int_{E} e^{x+y}dxdy$ where $E:$ Region lying between the two squares of side 2 and 4 centered at origin..?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Find the value of $\int\int_{E} e^{x+y}dxdy$ where $E:$ Region lying between the two squares of side 2 and 4 centered at origin and sides parallel to the axes.

The required value will obviously be

$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-2}^{2}e^{x+y}dxdy - \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{x+y}dxdy$

(Subtracting the smaller square from the larger one to get the region between them)

$$=(e^{2}-e^{-2})^2 - (e^{1}-e^{-1})^2 = 4\cdot(\sinh(2)-\sinh(1))(\sinh(2)+\sinh(1))$$

The book lists the answer as $4\sinh(3)\sinh(1)$

Is there a way to simply further to obtain this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

$$
\begin{align}
\dots &= \left(e^{2}-e^{-2}\right)^2 - \left(e-e^{-1}\right)^2\\
&= e^4-2+e^{-4}-e^2+2-e^{-2}\\
&= e^4-e^2-e^{-2}+e^{-4}\\
&= e^3\left(e-e^{-1}\right)-e^{-3}\left(e-e^{-1}\right)\\
&= \left(e^3-e^{-3}\right)\left(e-e^{-1}\right)\\
&= 4\sinh(3)\sinh(1)
\end{align}
$$

PS: to be honest, I figured it out backwards

Comment: francescop21 Do  you know of any formulas for $\sinh(a) \pm \sinh(b)?$

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Useful_relations)